# what's the way to access variables from serializeArray

Tags: ajax

I'm having trouble accessing variables in the post vars sent through to php from ajax. I always get null.

```
//in my jquery
var post_data = $('form#post').serializeArray();

//in my ajax
data: {
    'action': 'function_name_here',
    'post_data': post_data
},

//in my php
(isset($_REQUEST)) {
    $postData = $_REQUEST['post_data'];
}
```

If I use serialize() instead of serializeArray(), I can access variables like this:

```
parse_str($postData, $vars);
$postID = $vars['post_ID'];
```

Is it possible to use serializeArray()?

As suggested by Mat I tried $_POST. With both $_REQUEST and $_POST I get what I believe is a php array. I can print to the console and it looks like this (excerpt):

```
[{"name":"_wpnonce","value":"74a8352385"},{"name":"_wp_http_referer","value":"\/wp-admin\/post.php?post=13855&action=edit"},{"name":"user_ID","value":"1"}
```

I have tried things such as:
    $_POST['post_data']['user_ID']

But it's not working.

Comment: downvoted as there is nothing wordpress specific in this question. You should look at the browser developer tools to see what is actually being passed and do more debugging on the server side. most likely things are not being passed in the format you think they should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting the data from the `$_POST` server variable, not the `$_REQUEST` eg.

```
(isset($_POST)) {
    $postData = $_POST['post_data'];
}
```

`$_REQUEST` doesn't force you to figure out if the variable came from GET, POST, COOKIES, etc. It's useful for debugging scripts or when the variable might come form one of several sources. For instance you might have form information coming from a form (POST) or form a link (GET).

There are security considerations, however, since `$_REQUEST` captures data from several sources including cookies, so there's a potential for misbehavior if someone gets clever and you're not careful.

In order to use the posted JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) data in PHP you can use `json_decode()` eg.

`$postData = json_decode( $_POST['post_data'] );`

Then, for example, to access the variables you would need to use:

**_wpnonce** - `$postData[0]->value`

**_wp_http_referer** - `$postData[1]->value`

**user_ID** - `$postData[2]->value`

Or, if you wanted to return a tidier array that is more readable, you could use this on the json_decoded `$postData`:

```
$tidy_array = array();

foreach ( $postData as $object ){
    $tidy_array[$object->name] = $object->value;
}
```

Then you could access the data like so:

`$tidy_array['_wpnonce']`

`$tidy_array['_wp_http_referer]`

`$tidy_array['user_ID']`

Comment: you are right, but that doesn't actually answer the question, unless you have some explanation why $_REQUEST might have different values than $_POST

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Is that any better?

Comment: much better....